# Include glossary and nomenclature with LuaTeX

Tags: pdftex, luatex, glossaries, nomenclature

I'm a Latex beginner and I'm trying to include a glossary as well as nomenclature section at the beginning of my thesis. As I'm using the fontspec.sty package I have to use either XeTeX or LuaTeX for compiling. My main file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, parskip=half, titlepage, 12pt, BCOR=9mm, aps, DIV=16]{scrbook}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% abbreviations
\newacronym{ev}{EV}{Electric vehicle}

% nomenclature
\newglossaryentry{eg}{name=example,description=this is an example}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[title=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

The file compiles without errors, but neither abbreviations nor nomenclature are displayed in the document. I've read other threads saying that you need some compilation pipeline with pdflatex, but apparently I can't use that in my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: After compiling, the glossaries package will make some auxiliary files, (I believe .acn and .gls in your case). You need to run an external script called makeglossaries, then recompile. Why can't you use it in your case?  My best advice for LaTeX beginners: read the manual, it tells you what to do https://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it working. I thought I had to compile with pdflatex but it's working now :D